# UK visa ILR querying earliest date of application

Tags: visas, uk

Can anyone pin point on the Home Office website about entering the UK within 3 months of your visa start date being issued and being able to apply 28 days prior to the issue date of the visa?

I have only read it on third party websites.

Comment: I think this is a question about moving to live in the UK and if so, you should post it in expatriates.stackexchange

Comment: doesn't the ILR require you to be already in the UK for a certain number of years?